# c# winform : node expand and collapse in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is method that do it to be extended by icon in front of node without clicking node only?

Comment: Do you mean expand the node when it is clicked once anywhere on the node?

Comment: This needs a little better (more) description.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get a reference to a `TreeNode` object, you can call the following methods:

```
treeNode.Expand()
treeNode.Collapse()
```

These will expand and collapse any given node, assuming you want to do so programmatically rather than requiring the user to click the node.

Comment: Sorry.. My English is baby. Please, reference this site :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989255/expand-collapse-treeview-only-by-node-image-click Question of this site is same with my question. but site language is delphi